# How can I send a message using a bot and not send it again after restarting? Discord.PY

Tags: discord.py

Please tell me how you can send a message to a bot without a command, and then it will process it? So that after restarting but it continued to process? I started developing bots quite recently, but I still don't understand a lot of things. So far, I only came up with the idea that you can record the ID of the created message, then check it...

thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Please take the [StackOverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look at the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting a question, please make sure it is a Minimal, Reproducible Example